# Right exact functors are tensor products

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $F:\mod A\to \mod B$ be a functor from the category of finitely generated $A$-modules to the finitely generated $B$-modules. It is well-known that if $M$ is an $A-B$ bimodule, then $F(M)\cong M\otimes_A F(A)$. However, I am not able to see what would be the image of $m\otimes n\in M\otimes_A F(A)$ under this isomorphism. Any ideas would help. Thanks!

Comment: It's true for finitely _presented_ modules. Are you assuming that $A$ is noetherian?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming it is noetherian and artenian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me show that the claim is true when you replace "finitely generated" with "finitely presented". Since you are interested in the case where $A$ is noetherian, this is enough.

To begin, notice that $F(A^{\oplus n}) \cong F(A)^{\oplus n}$, since $F$ preserves direct sums. (In fact, any additive functor preserves direct sums.) Then, if $M$ is finitely presented, there is a right exact sequence of the form
$$A^{\oplus m} \longrightarrow A^{\oplus n} \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow 0$$
and so we have
$$F(A)^{\oplus m} \longrightarrow F(A)^{\oplus n} \longrightarrow F(M) \longrightarrow 0$$
because $F$ is right-exact. Thus $F$ is entirely determined by $F(A)$. Now, it is straightforward to see that $F(A)$ is an $A$-module, and ${-} \otimes_A F(A)$ is right exact, so this argument implies that $F$ is isomorphic to ${-} \otimes_A F(A)$ as a functor.

Comment: $F (A)$ is an $A$-module because $A$ acts on itself and $F$ is an additive functor. (Consider the maps $A \to A$ defined by $x \mapsto a x$ for a fixed element $a$.) I already explained how $F$ is determined by $F (A)$.

Comment: I am having trouble finishing the argument from where you left off ... how does the exact sequence $F(A)^{\oplus m} \longrightarrow F(A)^{\oplus n} \longrightarrow M\otimes_A F(A) \longrightarrow 0$ along with the exact sequence $F(A)^{\oplus m} \longrightarrow F(A)^{\oplus n} \longrightarrow F(M) \longrightarrow 0$ show that $F(M)\cong M\otimes_A F(A)$? I am not getting this ...

Comment: I mean, I cannot even see any map between $F(M)$ and $M\otimes_A F(A)$ ... are we assuming $F(A)$ is projective or something? But even then I cannot see how to conclude ...

Comment: (For simplicity, I am even willing to assume $A=B$ is commutative and Noetherian and $F$ is $A$-linear functor https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09MK ...)